# C# Generics - Manage each type adding 1

Tags: c#, generics

I'm new using Generics.

My function GetValuesGenerics give me some error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type '`ImproveMe.ViewModel.ControlYourWeight.DateTimeValuesGenerics`' to '`ImproveMe.ViewModel.ControlYourWeight.ValuesGenerics<T>`'

My Objective is that I give a min and maxValue and it generates me a range of value between min and max. I want to call the generator from an other class using Generics too. I don't really know if I have double or DateTime!

Could you help me out?

```
public static class ValuesGenericsGenerator<T>
{
    public static ValuesGenerics<T> GetValuesGenerics()
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(double))
        {
            return new DoubleValuesGenerics(1,1); ;
        }
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(DateTime))
        {
            return new DateTimeValuesGenerics(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(5));
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

public abstract class ValuesGenerics<T> 
{
    protected T minValue;

    protected T maxValue;

    public ValuesGenerics(T minValue, T maxValue)
    {
        this.minValue = minValue;
        this.maxValue = maxValue;
    }

    public abstract List<T> GenerateValues();
}

public class DoubleValuesGenerics : ValuesGenerics<double>
{
    public DoubleValuesGenerics(double minValue, double maxValue)
        : base(minValue, maxValue)
    {
    }

    public override List<double> GenerateValues()
    {
        List<double> values = new List<double>();
        do
        {
            values.Add(minValue);
            minValue++;
        }
        while (minValue <= maxValue);
        return values;
    }
}

public class DateTimeValuesGenerics : ValuesGenerics<DateTime>
{
    public DateTimeValuesGenerics(DateTime minValue, DateTime maxValue)
        : base(minValue, maxValue)
    {
    }

    public override List<DateTime> GenerateValues()
    {
        List<DateTime> values = new List<DateTime>();
        do
        {
            values.Add(minValue);
            minValue.AddDays(1);
        }
        while (minValue <= maxValue);
        return values;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's difficult to make this work. *you* know that you're only planning to return a `ValuesGenerics<double>` when `T` is `double` inside `GetValuesGenerics` - the compiler doesn't.

Comment: I don't really know too.

I want to call it from an otherclass using generic too. I don't know which type it is in the other class

My problem is: If what i'm doing makes sense or not ? ^^ Or better not use generic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by first casting the result of `GetValuesGenerics()` to a common, non generic base class of your `ValuesGenericsGenerator<T>` (e.g. object, for all c# objects).

```
public static class ValuesGenericsGenerator<T>
{
    public static ValuesGenerics<T> GetValuesGenerics()
    {
        object result;

        if (typeof(T) == typeof(double))
        {
            result = new DoubleValuesGenerics(1,1);
        }
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(DateTime))
        {
            result = new DateTimeValuesGenerics(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(5));
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

        return (ValuesGenerics<T>) result;
    }
}
```

Note:
Your current code allows you to only once call `GenerateValues()` and produces an infinite loop when using the `DateTime` version! You should change it to

```
public override List<double> GenerateValues()
{
    List<double> values = new List<double>();
    double val = minValue;
    do
    {
        values.Add(val);
        val++;
    }
    while (val <= maxValue);
    return values;
}

...

public override List<DateTime> GenerateValues()
{
    List<DateTime> values = new List<DateTime>();
    DateTime val = minValue;
    do
    {
        values.Add(val);
        val = val.AddDays(1);
    }
    while (minValue <= maxValue);
    return values;
}
```

Comment: you dont need to add a interim ValuesGenericsBase, you can just cast to object

Comment: Thank you for your help :D
I would love have people like you all day with me, i would increase my skills so fast ^^ :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly tell compiler the return type you are expecting or it cannot determine the return type if it is ValuesGenerics or ValuesGenerics or something else.

Not sure about the exact notation but it should be something like this:

```
public static class ValuesGenericsGenerator<T, TValues> where TValues : ValuesGenerics<T>
{
    public static TValues GetValuesGenerics()
    {
        // Do something.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :D
I would love have people like you all day with me, i would increase my skills so fast ^^ :)